# JQuery File Upload plugin, Internet Explorer, and IFrame transport

Tags: jquery, iframe, file-upload, knockout.js, internet-explorer-9

I'm using [this plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin) (just the basic version) and am utilizing all the neat features for progress updates to work with my own UI (using Knockout.js and Twitter Bootstrap). Here's some code snippets for context:

```
    // The file is sent to an ASP.NET MVC Web Api service to do all the business logic/DB stuff
    uploadUrl = http://web.api.url/?apikey=key

    $("#fileUpload" + "@index").fileupload({
        headers: {
            'Authorization': "@Html.AccessToken()",
            'Accept': $.support.ajax ? "application/json" : "text/plain"
        },
        url: uploadUrl,
        add: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                // add to KO viewmodel
            });
            data.submit();
        },
        fail: function (e, data) {
            var error = data.errorThrown;
            var text = data.textStatus;
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            // do some more viewmodel operations
        },
        progress: function (e, data) {
            var progressPercentage = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            // update viewmodel
        }
    });
```

The `#fileUpload<Index>` element is a file input

And this works great in Chrome, FF, and Safari but (surprise surprise) not in IE. I get a really strange response when trying to select a file from my file input - the browser opens a download dialog?!

```
Do you want to open or save ?apikey=key (61 bytes) from webapiserver?
```

I tried using IE's script debugger with breakpoints inside my fileupload event listeners, and it never even makes it inside. I've seen various posts and articles in my research that indicate that an accept-type of application/json will screw up IE, so I have a conditional in my code to try and handle that.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem lies on the server side.

IE is kinda dumbo and he accepts the first content-type which is offered by the server, so you always need to keep in mind to FIRST try to answer with `text/plain` or `text/html`.

This is however mentioned [in the FAQ from the jQuery plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-does-internet-explorer-prompt-to-download-a-file-after-the-upload-completes).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of the fix in C# that worked for me

```
    var result = Json(statuses, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    if (HttpContext.Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("application/json")) 
    {
        result.ContentType = "application/json";
    } 
    else // Hack for IE9 
    {
        result.ContentType = "text/plain";
    }

    return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the returned data is application/json. You need the server to specify content-type text/html to keep IE from interpreting it as a download.